# Typescript variable declaration and assignment in Firefox debugger

Tags: typescript, firefox, read-eval-print-loop, firefox-developer-tools

**I would like to create and manipulate a variable in Firefox Developer Tools.** For such a mundane task I'm having a heck of a time.

**>** denotes my input:

```
> var foo = 1;
undefined

> foo = 1
ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable foo 

> foo /* Executed after the two attempts above */
ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

I'm reading that declaration statements in javascript/typescript do not return a value, so REPL returns `undefined` as expected. I'm also reading doing just the assignment without the declaration is implicitly creating a global variable which throws a `ReferenceError` in strict mode (or default behavior in typescript), which explains the second attempt above.

It can't be the case that I'm stuck not being able to manipulate variables in Firefox. I'm having a specific problem with locally scoped variables exclusively with Firefox. **There must be some obvious thing I'm missing? How can I change my variables in Firefox?**

### Recreating the issue

- macOS Sierra 10.12.5
- Firefox 54.0.1 64-bit | `option` + `cmd` + `s` **or** open menu > developer > debugger
- After hitting a breakpoint
  inside the debugger

Comment: So what's the problem, the first one sets the variable just fine even if it returns `undefined` ?

Comment: @adeneo The problem is that I cannot read and verify what the variable is. How do I review that `foo` is in fact `1`?

Comment: You type `foo` in the console ?

Comment: @adeneo Correct. The third statement in my code block. I type `foo` after declaring and assigning. I get `ReferenceError`.

Comment: I can't reproduce, typying `> var foo = 1` and then `> foo` gives `1`

Comment: @adeneo I've updated my question. Typescript instead of javascript. Also must be after hitting a breakpoint in the debugger. Inside the console without and outside of a breakpoint does indeed work as I would expect.

Comment: I assume you are actually using the Firefox DevTools, as [Firebug's development is discontinued for quite some time now](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/) and its *Script* panel broke several Firefox versions ago. Can you add a screenshot to your question to verify that?

Comment: @SebastianZartner Yes, I was hazy on the history of firefox devtools/firebug. I included both just to be all-encompassing. I've updated my question to show how exactly I'm opening the developer tools. I also do not even have the firebug extension installed (if it exists anymore).

Comment: It looks like it's somehow related to the Firefox profile. I've tried this on two machines and only on one I could reproduce this once.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a bug in the DevTools, which should be [reported to them](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20Console&version=54%20Branch).

To find out what's causing it and create a reproducible test case for them, so they can fix it, there are several steps to follow.

First, you should try whether it works for you in a [fresh Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles). If you can reproduce the problem there, you should try to create a small test case and explain the steps to do to reproduce the problem. If it works in the new profile, the issue is normally either related to your preferences or your extensions.

To check whether it's related to your extensions, you should deactivate them all, restart your browser, and then try to reproduce the issue. If it works without the extensions, enable the extensions again one by one and check after enabling each one whether it still works to find the culprit.

If it's not related to the extensions, it's probably a preference. In that case you should compare the prefs.js file of your normal profile with the one of the new profile. To do so open the Firefox Menu > *?* > *Troubleshooting Information* > *Open Folder* (besides *Profile Folder*).
It may take some time but to find the preference(s) causing the bug you can copy each line in the prefs.js file of your normal profile which is different from the one of the new profile to the new prefs.js file and restarting Firefox after each one to test if it causes the issue.
If that's too much work for you, you may also add the prefs.js file of your normal profile to your bug report, *though note that it may contain private data*.